# Close question vote popup only partially visible

Tags: discussion, popups

When I try to close a question normally a close vote popup appear with a close button on the upper left corner of the popup. But today when I do it close vote popup appears but without close button and some of its upper part missing. I can not even scroll it. I only see the part of popup which is displayed in following image.

[image]

Where is close button?

**My environment**:

```
OS:- Windows XP SP3

Browser:- Google Chrome 10.0.648.205
```

Comment: @Arjan: Yes. Actually it is not the page.

Comment: @Arjan: I edited my question.

Comment: Can you indeed reproduce this yourself, @Harry?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes. The reproduction steps are in the answer. They are the similar steps I have done.

Comment: Really, in the answer... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be due to the exceptionally short question meaning there isn't enough vertical space. Fortunately, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> should close it. I'm not sure this is common enough to make it super-urgent.

In checking, it *looks* (to me, at least) like the dialog positions itself centrally. I'm having difficulty reproducing it exactly... which browser are you using (in case it is browser-dependent)?

The only way I can reproduce this screenshot is:

- shrink the page to an insane vertical size
- click the "close" link (bringing up the dialog)
- now with the dialog showing, make the browser window bigger

when the popup centered itself (in the middle bullet), it overlapped the screen edges due to the small size. Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, make the browser a reasonable size, and click close again.

Comment: The browser specs, for some unknown reason, are in the code block at the bottom of the question... Note there seems to be some screen real estate below the dialog though? There's the whole answer box there too.

Comment: @Arjan - found a repro (see edit), but I'm not sure I'd categorise it as a problem scenario

Comment: Just seen the edit in answer. Your steps are correct my window size is small. But the state is reserved when I restore the browser.

Comment: @Marc & Harry: The bottom-left link which reads 'cancel' might help.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment now that's just crazy talk ;p

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: It's good to know there are alternatives available.