# Flag popup is partially off screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, user-interface

I went to flag a question but decided against it before clicking "Flag Question". However, the close button wasn't visible and this shouldn't be happening.

A similar question is, [Close question vote popup only partially visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88439/169404) but that was due to the question being so short and it was a vertical issue.

I am having a hard time doing this again but here is the original screen shot without any horizontal cropping (latest version of Chrome):

[image: flag popup off screen]

Comment: Lightly tap on the left side of your screen. It will move back.

Comment: @Bart This isn't on a mobile device. Or are you just kidding?

Comment: I have no sense of humour whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the same issue as described in [Suggested edit popup gives poor layout in narrow windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136014/suggested-edit-popup-gives-poor-layout-in-narrow-windows), and thus should be fixed as well.